# $log(n)\leq f(n)$, $L\in DSPACE(f(n))$ means $L\in DTIME(C^{f(n)})$ for some C

Tags: complexity-theory

by definition log(n)=O(f(n)) therefor if M uses O(f(n)) cells it might as well uses log(n) cells, how do I continue?

Comment: We discourage "here is an exercise-style task, how do I solve it?" type questions.  We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving exercises for you is unlikely to achieve that. You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.  Part of our goal is to build up an archive of knowledge that will be useful for others in the future.  Also I suggest providing context and motivation, for instance, where did you encounter this problem statement?

Answer (score 0):

No, that doesn't follow.  1 is $\le$ a million.  Therefore if $M$ uses at most a million cells, it might as well use 1 cell.  Wait, there is something wrong with that logic...